# SQLAlchemy nested queries with single table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a single table(t1) with following entries.

```
seller_name | price | product
seller1     | 10.00 | a
seller2     | 9.00  | b
seller3     | 8.00  | a
seller2     | 9.00  | a
seller3     | 5.00  | b
seller1     | 8.00  | b
```

with the following code I can find all the products that seller1 sells

```
@app.route('/<seller_name>')#seller_name based results
def get_price(seller_name):
    t1 = User
    user_results = session.query(
        t1.seller_name, t1.product,t1.price.group_by(t1.product).filter(t1.seller_name==seller_name).all()
```

whit this following code I can find the each products cheapest seller with the price

```
lowest_price_sellers = session.query(
        t1.product,t1.seller_name, func.min(t1.price).label("min_price")
    ).group_by(t1.product).limit(100).all()
```

I would like to mix these two queries and find the following table

```
     For Seller1
Product | price | Lowest  | l.Price
a       | 10.00 | seller2 | 9.00
b       | 8.00  | seller3 | 5.00
```

I've tried nested queries and tried the join the queries but no avail. Nearly all of the examples online shows two different tables and I cant wrap my head around it.